# LOAD DATA FROM S3 falsely returns error in codeigniter query method

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-s3

I´m hosting a codeigniter app on AWS and one method in that app is running a

```
"LOAD DATA FROM S3 'S3 path' ... "
```

This is essentially the same as a LOAD DATA INFILE query but customized in AWS Aurora to read files from S3 instead of your local volume. The query executes as expected but CI's

```
$this->db->error()
```

returns an array indicating that an error occurred. The content of that array is

```
[0, '']
```

First I thought it was a timeout but after reducing the size if the file to import and making sure the records was imported I started to suspect that CI's DB driver aren't designed to handle the result from that query.
The query don´t really return any data and I guess that confuses CI.

Is there any good way to bypass this behavior in CI without altering the frameworks "sourcecode"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: CodeIgniter uses `mysql_errno` and `mysql_error` to get those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that since the DB driver class called `MySQLi` returns the following to `$this->db` instance in the model (see `errno` and `error` attributes)

```
[_mysqli:protected] => mysqli Object
    (
        [affected_rows] => 1
        [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b382534eeb34d9ed79345235b8bae2234b287afcs21ad4e $
        [client_version] => 50012
        [connect_errno] => 0
        [connect_error] => 
        [errno] => 0
        [error] => 
        [error_list] => Array
            (
            )
```

I will never get any more information about the error then what `mysql_errno` and `mysql_error` returns to the driver.  So instead if error checking the query like this

```
if($this->db->error())
{
    return false;
}
```

I can simply do this

```
if(is_array($this->db->error()) && 0 !== $this->db->error()[0])
{
    return false;
}
```

Errors are returned in array format or false from `$this->db->error()` and thus it is very simple to check if the errorcode is zero. If it is zero we can asume that the query executed as planned and that the import has completed. 
The reason that we get an array instead of false from $this->db->error() is that no result was returned from the query which CI expects.

So... a simple solution after all.